# Angular - Add class names based on image dimensions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to set class names for images based on its dimensions. I get the dimensions using onload(). Everything works fine, but the function itself is running infinitely and breaks the application.

No other JS answers worked for me since I'm rendering images from select box, this function triggers only after selecting an image.

This is the code I've tried

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bai7wg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I have commented out lines in getImgDimensions(ev) uncomment it and you'll see the console is flooded.

Comment: You can't call a function like that since it will be triggered each time the angular lifecycle gets triggered.  Even changing the change detection to onpush will end up executing this function more times than you want.

Comment: @Osakr is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: you could create an object with the data u need. At load time when u get the images you could check the dimensions for all images and store that information in an object. Later on from the template you could use that object's data

Comment: Seems plausible, but the images list could be more in numbers.